# Find all columns with a date pattern in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to identify whether a column in my dataframe has a date or not.  For context, my real dataset has hundreds of columns, and I can't go through and manually identify if a column is a date or not.  Ultimately, I need to get the dates in a similar format so that I can compare different versions of my datasets and see what has changed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date1':['07/23/01', '06/25/17', np.nan, '1/5/06'],
        'date2':[np.nan, '12/01/08', '9/02/03', np.nan],
        'str1':['aaaaf', '23fgsafg', 'dsf5t', np.nan]})

mask = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.match('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}').all())
```

I've tried the following code, but each of these variables come up as "false".
What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype.name == 'object':
        if all(df[col].str.contains(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}', regex=True, na=True)):
            print(f'{col} column contains a date-like string')

# => date1 column contains a date-like string
#    date2 column contains a date-like string
```

Note that to find a regex match anywhere in the input string you need to use `Series.str.contains` with `regex=True` (as it is based on `re.search` method), since `Series.str.match` requires the match to only appear at the start of string (as it is based on `re.match` method).

`na=True` is necessary to make all `np.nan` values truthy when checking if `all` values in a column return `True`.

Comment: When I first asked this question, this code above worked just fine.  Now i'm getting an error that says "UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.  return func(self, *args, **kwargs)"  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: @BPC `r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}'` has no capturing groups. So, no idea what you have got.

Comment: I had changed the regex slightly, but when test it on just a single column it works fine.          `bb = existing_trk.copy() `            
`bb['ppm_review_date_TF'] = bb['ppm_review_date'].str.contains(r"\d{1,4}(?:-|/)\d{1,2}(?:-|/)\d{1,4}", regex=True, na=True) `        
`bb['ppm_review_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(bb['ppm_review_date'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")`

Comment: @BPC Right, it works. Also, you can use character classes when you group single chars, `r"\d{1,4}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,4}"`

Comment: sorry- i'm realizing the issue is that the new upload had text values of "None" in place of <null>, so the last if statement wasn't recognizing the column as meeting the criteria.  Good to know about the character classes too! Thanks again for the help.